# Migrate large database from MySQL 8 to MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I need a solution to migrate a large database from MYSQL 8 to MariaDB (any version, but preferably 10.4)
I have already searched the MariaDB site and I have done Google searches on the subject but I have not found anything yet.
Unfortunately, the solution to run a mysqldump seems to me not very feasible, because the database that I have to migrate is at least 40 GB large (of physical disk space).

Comment: It may take a while, but why is the dump unfeasible, 40 GB isn't an issue with today's hard drive sizes?

Comment: You claim you haven't found anything but you've obviously found about mysqldump. Perhaps you want to rephrase the question and ask about your specific needs (e.g. dump a large database over slow/unreliable network, almost full disk... whatever).

Comment: 40GB and more is the size of the files on filesystem, a mysqldump will result in a single file of about 150-160GB

Comment: Right, that's about the size of the scheduled backup copies I take in my work PC. And in your case that is an issue that needs to be addressed because...?

Answer (score 2):

In general MariaDB is designed as a drop-in replacement for MySQL.

Since MySQL 8.0 it's unfortunately not possible anymore to simply replace MySQL with MariaDB and use the same data-files as before.

The only way to move to MariaDB from MySQL 8.0 or higher is using `mysqldump`.

See here for reference: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/upgrading-from-mysql-to-mariadb/

> If you are using MySQL 8.0 or above, you have to use mysqldump to move your database to MariaDB.

Another solution that came to my mind was downgrading from MySQL 8.0 to MySQL 5.7 - unfortunately that is not possible either:

> Downgrade from MySQL 8.0 to MySQL 5.7, or from a MySQL 8.0 release to a previous MySQL 8.0 release, is not supported. The only supported alternative is to restore a backup taken before upgrading. It is therefore imperative that you backup your data before starting the upgrade process.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/downgrading.html

I think you have to take the time for a `mysqldump`.

Sorry m8.

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:

```
mysqldump -h mysql_8_host ... | mysql -h mariadb_10_host ...
```

That avoids instantiating the intermediate file that you say might be 160GB.

Plan B:

```
mysqldump -h mysql_8_host ... | gzip >dump.gz
gunzip <dump.gz | mysql -h mariadb_10_host ...
```

The compressed file will probably be less than 40GB.  For one thing, it will not have the indexes.  (They will be rebuilt in the second step.)

In either case...

There may be incompatibilities between the two versions.  Check out the parameters of both mysql's `mysqldump`, which might have backward-compatibility options, and mariadb's `mysqldump`, which might be prepared to accept 8.0 input.